# C# - System.InvalidCastException in Datagridview

Tags: c#

I retrieved one row from datagridview using following code (in datagridview cellclick event)

```
DataGridViewRow dtrow = gvUserFormStatus.Rows[e.RowIndex];
```

I try to get cell value(first cell) from datagridviewrow and convert into double using below code

```
double x = (double)(dtrow.Cells[0].Value);
```

I m getting error
An unhandled exception of type '**System.InvalidCastException**' occurred.

Additional information: **Specified cast is not valid**.

Here the code for writing gridview

```
SqlDataAdapter mydataadapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from user_table", myconnection);
DataSet mydataset = new DataSet();
mydataadapter.Fill(mydataset);

DataTable dtUserFormStatus = mydataset.Tables[0];
gvUserFormStatus.DataSource = dtUserFormStatus;
```

In sql,datatype for this particular field is **nvarchar(10)**

Thanks

Comment: well, the error is quite clear, the object in "Value" is not a `double`, and it's something that cannot be cast to `double`. What are you putting in your rows?

Comment: value in that cell is 10.000

Comment: Sure, but what is the type? It's defininively not a double. Might be a string, something else? Edit your question and add how you enter the values in the datagrid.

Comment: Hi Gimly...I just added the code....let me know this is enough or any additional information required...Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually prefer `FormattedValue`

```
double x = double.Parse(dtrow.Cells[0].FormattedValue.ToString());
```

Alternate

```
double x = double.Parse(dtrow.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
```

Comment: Thanks...it working....double.Parse(dtrow.Cells[0].Value.ToString()) is also working

Answer (score 0):

The DataGridViewCell object in Cells[0] declares Value property as Object. You are explicitly converting an object to double with the () operator, which thrown an exception, no matter the value.

This is your case:

```
  Object number = 123;
  double doubleNumber = (double)number; --> InvalidCastException
```

Use instead

`Convert.ToDouble(Cells[0].Value)`

Comment: Well, not no matter the value - if the value is a boxed double the cast will succeed...

Comment: `Object number = 123.435; double doubleNumber = (double)number;` will work just fine.